# How do I refresh sqlite database in SQLite Database Browser?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I am using python to connect and make changes with a sqlite database. On the side, I am viewing the tables and database structure of the sqlite db using DB Browser for SQLite.

After I run my python code and make changes, I normally have to close the DB Browser and reopening it again. Is there a way or button in DB Browser I can refresh and update the db without closing and reopening?

Comment: At the "Browse Data" tab, right next to to table's combo box there's the refresh button.

Comment: @forpas doesn't work for refreshing the database structure tho

Comment: Is [tag:db-browser-sqlite] the same as [tag:sqlite-browser]?